# classname get confused when i use if in jsx in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

hi im using nextJs i have problem using if else in jsx .
when i use if the classes of elements doesn't load correctly.

> this is my code :

```
            <Nav>
                {
                    login ?
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <a className='text-white mx-1'>Welcome</a>
                            <a onClick={logOut} id={style.test} className={` text-danger mx-1`}>Log out</a>

                        </React.Fragment>

                        :
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <Link href="/register" prefetch={false}>
                                <a className='nav-link'>register</a>
                            </Link>

                            <Nav.Link className='text-info' eventKey={2}  onClick={handleShow}>
                                Login
                            </Nav.Link>
                        </React.Fragment>
                }

            </Nav>
```

[image]

log out should get (text-danger) class but it gets another class

Answer (score 0):

Change `className="text-danger mx-1"`

```
<React.Fragment>
    <a className='text-white mx-1'>Welcome</a>
    <a onClick={logOut} id={style.test} className="text-danger mx-1"}>Log out</a>

</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: i changed , it didnt work . i have this problem only in if statment :(

Comment: Nothing to help :(

Answer (score 0):

we can directly specify the className if thats not a variable .

```
<a onClick={logOut} id={style.test} className="text-danger mx-1">Log out</a>
```

[image]

Comment: i changed , it didnt work . i have this problem only in if statment :(

Comment: Nothing to help :(

Comment: i tested the same and it worked . Make sure you dont have any global styles which are overriding for anchor tag <a>